# Left join two tables returning null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these 2 tables `@tmp` and `@tmp1`:

[image]

I am writing a query like,

```
SELECT  
    repperiod, sequence, t1.title, question,
    (CASE WHEN t2.Answer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Met,
    (CASE WHEN t2.Answer = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NA,
    (CASE WHEN (ISNULL(t2.Answer,3) <> 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MetNotMet 
FROM
    @tmp t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @temp1 t2 ON t1.ScheduleQuestionID = t2.ScheduleQuestionID 
              AND t1.deptsplit = t2.DeptSplit
```

It's returning Met, NA, MetNotMet with `NULL` values.

What's wrong in the query?

@tmp has more rows than @tmp1. So not all Question Ids from @tmp are present in @tmp1.

Some records have multiple answers for same question. so I am splitting by dept.

I want to take all rows from @tmp. So I am creating left join.

Comment: what current result do you get? what are your primary and foreign keys?

Comment: sorry not null I am getting all 0 values for met, na and metnotmet. These are 2 temporary tables i am creating in stored procedure. No primary and foreign keys.

Comment: Start debugging this by including t2.answer in the select.

Comment: if i select question ids from both tables, dept split from t2, title from t2, in above query, giving me all nulls

Comment: then t1.ScheduleQuestionID = t2.ScheduleQuestionID 
              AND t1.deptsplit = t2.DeptSplit is failing. Check the field types are the same and if string trim them to remove any spaces.